# Converting REST data to components

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My specific situation for this question involves transforming inbound links into LinkComponents that use actions to scroll, but it's perhaps better to generalize it: what's the proper method to convert inbound REST data into an ember component?

An example: say I have the string `<a href="#foo">Foo anchor link</a>` coming in from data source of choice.  I have written a custom adapter and serializer to properly transform the inbound data to jsonapi standards, and I've defined a model to store it.

I wish to convert these anchors to components, or in general, to something that contains 'data-ember-action', much like all the template-rendered content that already exist elsewhere in my app.  For awhile I believed that RenderBuffer was the solution to my problem - simply create the component I wish to replace the anchor substring with, render it to a RenderBuffer, and use that to get the corresponding string output that I can then insert in the content.  I have a (possibly unfounded) suspicion, however, that this is oversimplifying the problem, and neglects certain internal operations that occur behind the scenes during template rendering in Ember.  It also appears that RenderBuffer is [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11431), meaning that even if this is a viable approach currently, it is not the appropriate way to do this.

Anyone have any advice on how to approach this issue?

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. Could you extract the data and then render the links that way? Or use the `{{component}}` helper.

Comment: I like `DS.Transform`s, because it allows me to parse something like your html string, into a hash of useful data that can be used in a `{{component}}` helper like @locks suggests

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response.  Thank you, I appreciate the answers, but I have to admit - I'm still not seeing a path to a result.  The `{{component}}` helper seems well suited towards dynamically rendering a component where you already know in your template you'll need one, but not which one.  I'm looking to potentially create something the template does not know about, based on the incoming data.  I tried the `DS.Template` approach that you suggested @Grapho, but it still doesn't seem to be a place where an unknown component could be wedged into the rendering process.